# Double data type returns wrong value

Tags: java

Is there any solution for double data type returns 1.10 instead of 1.1. My problem is if i assign value 1.10 to double variable than it prints 1.1. it ignores the last zero. so what i have to do for print 1.10 full number.

Comment: This question is a bit thin, and therefore will likely be closed, but I would opine that your problem might actually be do to the _formatting_ you are using when printing your `double` value, rather than the `double` itself.

Comment: take a look - 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: Hi, Shrupal. Welcome to SO. Don't get disappointed by the downvotes. In this case it is just to indicate that there are duplicates of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The trailing zeros are automatically excluded. I would recommend using a `String` instead of a `double` to preserve those zeros. If you need to use it later for calculations, you can convert it to `double` using `Double.parseDouble()`, though this will remove the trailing zeros.

Comment: You should take a look at the duplicates too.